# How can I force surrounding elements to move in response to a change in size of one of the elements?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I found some code that displays a group of circles. I slightly modified the code to allow the user to click on any of the circles to change its radius. The problem is that that enlarged circle overlaps the other other circle. I want the other circles to move so that the larger circle doesn't overlap any of the adjacent circles. Here is the code I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script>

var width = 960,
    height = 500;

var nodes = d3.range(200).map(function() { return {radius: Math.random() * 12 + 4}; }),
        root = nodes[0],
        color = d3.scale.category10();

root.radius = 0;
root.fixed = true;

var force = d3.layout.force()
        .gravity(0.05)
        .charge(function(d, i) { return i ? 0 : -2000; })
        .nodes(nodes)
        .size([width, height]);

force.start();

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(nodes.slice(1))
        .enter().append("circle")
        .attr("r", function(d) { return d.radius; })
        .style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i % 3); })
        .on("click", function (d) {
            d3.select(this).attr("r", 30);
            force.start();
        });

force.on("tick", function(e) {
    var q = d3.geom.quadtree(nodes),
            i = 0,
            n = nodes.length;

    while (++i < n) q.visit(collide(nodes[i]));

    svg.selectAll("circle")
            .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.x; })
            .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.y; });
});

function collide(node) {
    var r = node.radius + 16,
            nx1 = node.x - r,
            nx2 = node.x + r,
            ny1 = node.y - r,
            ny2 = node.y + r;
    return function(quad, x1, y1, x2, y2) {
        if (quad.point && (quad.point !== node)) {
            var x = node.x - quad.point.x,
                    y = node.y - quad.point.y,
                    l = Math.sqrt(x * x + y * y),
                    r = node.radius + quad.point.radius;
            if (l < r) {
                l = (l - r) / l * .5;
                node.x -= x *= l;
                node.y -= y *= l;
                quad.point.x += x;
                quad.point.y += y;
            }
        }
        return x1 > nx2 || x2 < nx1 || y1 > ny2 || y2 < ny1;
    };
}

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, but that does not cause the adjacent circles to move. The larger circle still overlaps the adjacent circles.

Comment: You also have to set the radius attribute to the new value `d.radius = 30`.